# How to block a user agent using mod_rewrite in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to block the access to this user agent who's visiting me: `Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Seekport Crawler; http://seekport.com/` (with no `)` at the end, its not a fault).

I have tried this one (with two more agents)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} OnalyticaBot [NC, OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Re-re Studio (+http://vip0.ru/) [NC, OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Seekport Crawler; http://seekport.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

I have tried a couple more with this sintax (using entire string and using only "Seekport") but still seeing the agent user asking for in the log

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.(user_agent1|user_agent2).$ [NC]
```

Could you help me?

Comment: For starters, you should put your test patterns in quotes, since they contain spaces.

Comment: Not working. Right now i´m using:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.(OnalyticaBot|"Re-re Studio (+http://vip0.ru/)"|"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Seekport Crawler; http://seekport.com/").*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]

and Re-re Studio (+http://vip0.ru/)" is now visiting my web (I have blocked the ip anyway, but would like to know how to write the rule for htaccess)

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Re-re Studio (+http://vip0.ru/) [NC, OR]
> ```

By default, the 2nd argument to the `RewriteCond` directive is a regular expression (regex), so any *meta* characters (eg. `+` and `.`) need to be properly escaped. But importantly, *spaces* are delimiters in Apache config files so these also need to be escaped, otherwise, the directive will be wholly invalid. On Apache, the above will result in a fatal error (500 Internal Server Error) due to "bad flag delimiters". On LiteSpeed, it will simply fail silently.

Spaces can be "escaped" by either:

- Precede the space with a backslash. eg. `\`  in `hello\ world`
- Or, use a `\s` shorthand character class to represent any white-space character. eg. `hello\sworld`.
- Or, enclose the entire argument in double-quotes. eg. `"hello world"`.

`[NC, OR]` - However, there should be no spaces in the flag delimiters argument. This should be `[NC,OR]` (no space).

So, the above could be written like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} OnalyticaBot [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Re-re Studio (\+http://vip0\.ru/)" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Mozilla/5\.0 (compatible; Seekport Crawler; http://seekport\.com/$" [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

The regex `.*` in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* can be simplified to just `^` (which is more efficient) and the `L` flag is not required when using `F` - it is implied.

If you want to match an entire user-agent string then you can use the `=` (lexicographical string comparison for equality) prefix operator (together with double-quotes) on the *CondPattern* to test for an exact match.

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "=This is the exact user-agent I want to block"
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

In the above example, the string `This is the ... block` is an ordinary string, not a regex.